# How can I programmatically create a @Test with JUnit?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

I have the feeling I'm missing something but I didn't find anything around here.

I have a `testAllPath` method with `@Test` label that collects a list of file paths and, with a loop, performs my controls, let's say checking that the path is correct.
When I open the JUnit short view I see, obviously, one Test called `testAllPath` with the result, and in failed case the details of it.
But I can't immediately distinguish which path is wrong among all, so the question is:

**How can I make every single control in a loop a single test?**

or more generically

**How can I programmatically create a @Test?**

Thanks

Comment: This can help you: https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks @DavidPérezCabrera, if you add this like answer I will mark as solution.

Comment: Even thanks to all users are fast unuseful clicked with no explenation. U make this place a worse place.

Answer (score 1):

Add a message to the assert:

```
    assertTrue("Problem with folder " + file.getName, file.exists());
```

Make sure the message is detailed enough to help you pinpoint the problem. In this case, it feels pretty reasonable to print the name of the file.